# Kill Xvnc daily

Tags: cron, vnc

First of all sorry, I'm a little noob here trying to learn.
I'm trying to kill all Xvnc sessions daily without restarting my server.
I tried putting in crontab:

```
37 * * * * root /usr/bin/pkill Xvnc
```

( I only selected minutes to check if cron executes the job) but it doesn't work.
When I run

```
# pkill Xvnc
```

the Xvnc session is killed successfully.
Can you please advise? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: "tried putting in crontab" how exactly? if you used `sudo crontab -e` then you shouldn't  include the user field `root` (that's only required for jobs specified via `/etc/cron`)

Comment: Many thanks, removing user seemed to do the trick!